# Could not create converter for java.io.InputStream in Quarkus with Reasteasy-Reactive and JAX-RS

Tags: kotlin, jax-rs, quarkus, resteasy

I have the following endpoint

```
@POST
@Path("/images")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("application/json")
fun upload(@FormParam(value = "file") fileInputStream: InputStream, @FormParam(value = "comment") comment: String): Response {
    anotherClass.save(fileInputStream, comment)
    return Response.ok().build()
}
```

Running a test against this endpoint returns this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create converter for java.io.InputStream for method javax.ws.rs.core.Response upload(java.io.InputStream fileInputStream, java.lang.String altText) on class SampleClass of type FORM
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.processor.ServerEndpointIndexer.handleOtherParam(ServerEndpointIndexer.java:327)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.processor.ServerEndpointIndexer.handleOtherParam(ServerEndpointIndexer.java:92)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.processor.EndpointIndexer.extractParameterInfo(EndpointIndexer.java:1341)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.processor.EndpointIndexer.createResourceMethod(EndpointIndexer.java:536)
... 14 more
```

Adding resteasy-multipart dependency is also not working, since it is incompatible with resteasy-reactive.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you read https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#multipart?

Comment: following the guide results in the same error
Could not create converter for org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.multipart.FileUpload

Comment: Do you have a sample somewhere I can check?